# Erro na lambda com join quando coloco um Groupby

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Nessa lambda, está dando erro no select em t1 e t2. Se coloco Key diz que não reconhece TotalLiquido e os campos em t2. Se removo o Groupby funciona.

```
public List<LiberacaoItensDTO> GetLibItems(double id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Join
                (
                    contexto.ItensLibs,
                    t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
                    t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
                    (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }
                )                
                .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento && a.t1.IdOrcamento == id)
                .GroupBy(gb => new { gb.t1.IdOrcamento })
                .Select(item => new LiberacaoItensDTO
                {
                    TotalVenda = item.t1.TotalLiquido,
                    TotalLucro = item.t2.Total - (item.t2.Qtde*item.t2.Custo)
                }).ToList();

            //double totallucro = lista.Sum(t => t.TotalLucro);
           // lista.ForEach(t => t.TotalLucro = totallucro);

            return lista;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando voce usa o `GroupBy` Voce fica com uma lista de grupos. Para voce perceber, no seu caso, voce ficará com tantos grupos consoante o número de ids de orcamentos.

Se ainda nao deu para perceber pode verificar que o `GroupBy` retorna `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, ou seja uma sequencia de grupos. Cada grupo tem uma propriedade `Key` que corresponde á key usada para formar cada grupo. Como pode imaginar puderá haver mais que um elemento em cada grupo.

Por isso a solucao depende da sua lógica. Se voce souber que cada grupo só puderá ter um elemento, o melhor mesmo puderá ser nao usar o `GroupBy`. Se de fato tiver vários elementos, terá que mudar o seu código.

```
var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
    .Join
    (
        contexto.ItensLibs,
        t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
        t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
        (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }
    )                
    .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento && a.t1.IdOrcamento == id)
    .GroupBy(gb => new { gb.t1.IdOrcamento })
    .Select(group => new LiberacaoItensDTO
    {
        TotalVenda = group.Sum(item => item.t1.TotalLiquido),
        TotalLucro = group.Sum(item => item.t2.Total - (item.t2.Qtde*item.t2.Custo))
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Olá Bruno, a idéia e ter um somatório no gráfico. O que passa é que a tabela de itens ela printa no gráfico a margem, tantas vezes quanto é a qtde de itens e preciso mostrar apenas uma fatia no gráfico. Então, criei um outro DTO para carregar o lucro da tabela de itens e nem sei se isso vai acontecer.