# Como evitar o somatório de itens em minha lambda. Resultado não é o esperado

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tenho essa lambda:

```
[Route("getliberaitens/{id}")]
        public List<LiberacaoItensDTO> GetLibItems(double id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                .Join
                (
                    contexto.ItensLibs,
                    t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
                    t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
                    (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }
                )
                .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento && a.t1.IdOrcamento == id)
                .GroupBy(gb => new { gb.t1.IdOrcamento })
                .Select(item => new LiberacaoItensDTO
                {
                    TotalVenda = item.Sum(a => a.t1.TotalLiquido),
                    TotalLucro = item.Sum(a => a.t2.Total - (a.t2.Qtde * a.t2.Custo))
                }).ToList();

            //double totallucro = lista.Sum(t => t.TotalLucro);
            lista.ForEach(t => t.TotalLucro = double.Parse(string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", t.TotalLucro)));

            return lista;
        }
```

Esse é o resulta pego no Postman

```
"TotalVenda": 5470,
"TotalLucro": 273.71
```

Acontece que esse resultado está errado. Para esse orçamento o TotalVenda é : **1094**. Chegou a esse resultado, pois no Sum, ele somou pela quantidade de itens, que nesse caso essa venda possui 5 itens. Se eu retiro o **Sum** dá erro em t1 e t2. O total lucro nesse caso é de 30% do total da venda, o que não dá o valor acima. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda em como resolver a questão do **SUM**?

Comment: para você tira do sum teria que incluir no group by , se TotalLiquido for uma lista com os mesmo velares você poderia também usar o first.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, e como eu faria isso? Veja que TotalVenda e TotalLucro fazem parte da LiberacaoItensDTO e os demais campos vem das Models Liberacao e ItensLib. E como eu faria isso? De que forma incluir no Groupby? Eu agrupei, para quando eu apresentar o chart, a fatia do lucro não se repetir de acordo com a quantidade de itens, como estava acontecendo.

Comment: para por no group by basta inclui no new { gb.t1.IdOrcamento , gb. " _ " . TotalLiquido } .. e no select você acessar com o item.key.TotalLiquido

Comment: esta um pouco confuso o que você quer fazer, teria como montar a query em sql e posta na pergunta como ela seria ?

Comment: O comentário saiu errado. Da forma passada está funcionando. Se quiser responder, eu marco a resposta.

Comment: poste sua solução... não dar para entende sua estrutura.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, como falei está ok.

Comment: acredito que tenha sido da forma que respondi, certo ?

Comment: Veja se a resposta esta de acordo com o que tinha comentado.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu [falei na pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247643/erro-na-lambda-com-join-quando-coloco-um-groupby/247646?noredirect=1#comment507669_247646) tudo isto dependeria da lógica e dos seus dados.

Pelo que percebi voce pode ter vários elementos no grupo, mas todos eles parecem ter dados semelhantes (ou mesmo iguais), e daí voce só quer um deles. Pode usar o `FirstOrDefault`

```
var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
    .Join
    (
        contexto.ItensLibs,
        t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
        t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
        (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }
    )                
    .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento && a.t1.IdOrcamento == id)
    .GroupBy(gb => new { gb.t1.IdOrcamento })
    .Select(group => new LiberacaoItensDTO
    {
        TotalVenda = group.FirstOrDefault(item => item.t1.TotalLiquido),
        TotalLucro = group.FirstOrDefault(item => item.t2.Total 
            - (item.t2.Qtde*item.t2.Custo))
    }).ToList();
```

Creio que outra forma de resolver o problema seria usando o `Distinct`.

```
lista = contexto.Liberacoes
    .Join(contexto.ItensLibs,
        t1 => t1.IdOrcamento,
        t2 => t2.IdOrcamento,
        (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }
    )
    .Where(a => a.t1.IdOrcamento == a.t2.IdOrcamento && a.t1.IdOrcamento == id)
    .Distinct(comparer)
    .Select(item=> new LiberacaoItensDTO
    {
        TotalVenda = item.t1.TotalLiquido,
        TotalLucro = item.t2.Total - (item.t2.Qtde * item.t2.Custo))
    });
```

Mas aí voce tem que impletementar um `IEqualityComparer` para comparar por Id de orcamento.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme explicado nos comentários, bastaria incluir no group by e usar o Key no select, ficaria algo assim.

```
.GroupBy(gb => new { gb.t1.IdOrcamento, gb.t1.TotalLiquido })
.Select(item => new LiberacaoItensDTO
{
    TotalVenda = item.Key.TotalLiquido,
    TotalLucro = item.Sum(a => a.t2.Total - (a.t2.Qtde * a.t2.Custo))
}).ToList();
```

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083631/2740371) tem uma boa referencia de uso.